# proper uses of "it"

Tags: pronouns

In Spanish "it" doesn't exist, therefore sometimes it gets a bit confusing when and how to use it, if you name the noun, do you still have to use it?

Examples:

> a) The house is an old house and is empty.
>
> b) Is [it] her hair curly?
>
> c) This wedding [it] is becoming more and more boring!

Should I use "it" in these three sentences?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking about here. Your example (a) is valid, in that it's *possible* to simply "delete" the second instance of the repeated element ***the house***, instead if replacing it with the pronoun ***it***. But your examples (b) and (c) have no obvious connection to "the proper use of **it**".

Comment: Thank you, what I´dlike to find out with  with examples b) & c) is:  Can I say: Is it her hair curly?  and  This weeding it´s becoming more and more  boring? Another one: Is it your dog happy when it sees you?

Comment: @claudiosepulveda No, you would not use both it and a noun in the same clause. The exception would be "This wedding, it's becoming more and more boring", but note that a comma is in between "This wedding" and "it's".

Comment: ¿No se puede decir "Lo he visto", en que "lo" funciona como "it"?  I know it isn't exactly the same, but it's similar (although Spanish sometimes confuses me by throwing le/la/lo in where you *wouldn't* put "it" in English, like "una peli, en la que", where you wouldn't say in English, "a film, in it that".)

Comment: The word **family** is singular. My family is great! // The word **people** is plural. Those people are rude. // (Sorry Nathan; it was a quick question easily answered.)

Answer (score 3):

"It" is intended to replace a noun. However, when using "it", you should make sure you have proper context. For example, when asking about someone's house, you would want to say:

> Is your house nearby?

However, if the house has been mentioned before, you can use "it":

> Bob: My house is rather small.
>
> Alice: Is it nearby?

Here it is clear that "it" refers to Bob's house.

For your sentences, you should only use "it" if proper context has been given in the conversation before, or in the sentence itself:

> **It** is an old house.
>
> Is **her hair** curly?
>
> **This wedding** is becoming more and more boring!

In the first sentence, context is given in the form of "an old house", so you do not need to say "the house".